# The app on the login screen gives a black screen on tablet only

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have built this app for mobile and tablet and everything is working perfectly until i faced this issue.
the app works perfectly fine on mobile but gives me a black screen on tablet

this is the error

```
I/flutter (28116): #717    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5322:16)
I/flutter (28116): #718    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5016:7)
I/flutter (28116): #719    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5628:5)
I/flutter (28116): #720    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:107:11)
I/flutter (28116): #721    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3685:15)
I/flutter (28116): #722    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5322:16)
I/flutter (28116): #723    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:11)
I/flutter (28116): #724    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5016:7)
I/flutter (28116): #725    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5485:5)
I/flutter (28116): #726    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3685:15)
I/flutter (28116): #727    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5322:16)
I/flutter (28116): #728    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:11)
I/flutter (28116): #729    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5016:7)
I/flutter (28116): #730    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5485:5)
I/flutter (28116): #731    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3685:15)
I/flutter (28116): #732    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6441:14)
I/flutter (28116): #733    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3685:15)
I/flutter (28116): #734    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6441:14)
I/flutter (28116): #735    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3685:15)
I/flutter (28116): #736    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5322:16)
I/flutter (28116): #737    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5016:7)
I/flutter (28116): #738    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5628:5)
I/flutter (28116): #739    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3685:15)
I/flutter (28116): #740    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5322:16)
I/flutter (28116): #741    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:11)
I/flutter (28116): #742    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5016:7)
I/flutter (28116): #743    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2779:19)
I/flutter (28116): #744    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:916:21)
I/flutter (28116): #745    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:360:5)
I/flutter (28116): #746    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1297:15)
I/flutter (28116): #747    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1227:9)
I/flutter (28116): #748    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1085:5)
I/flutter (28116): #749    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:13)
I/flutter (28116): #750    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:401:5)
I/flutter (28116): #751    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:140:31)
I/flutter (28116): (elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)
I/flutter (28116): 
I/flutter (28116): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (28116): Another exception was thrown: Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
I/flutter (28116): Another exception was thrown: Tried to build dirty widget in the wrong build scope.
```

this is my `main.dart` file

```
import 'package:b2b_wholesale/res/routes_manager.dart';
import 'package:b2b_wholesale/utils/navigation_service.dart';
import 'package:b2b_wholesale/view_model/cart_model/cart_model.dart';
import 'package:b2b_wholesale/view_model/categories_view_model/categories_view_model.dart';
import 'package:b2b_wholesale/view_model/home_view_model/home_view_model.dart';
import 'package:b2b_wholesale/view_model/login_view_model/login_view_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);

  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<LoginViewModel>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => LoginViewModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<HomeViewModel>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => HomeViewModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<CategoriesViewModel>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => CategoriesViewModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Cart>(create: (BuildContext context) => Cart()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: NavigationService().navigationKey,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: Routes.splashRoute,
        onGenerateRoute: RoutesManager.getRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when i remove `ChangeNotifierProvider<Cart>(create: (BuildContext context) => Cart()),` the login works but when i get to the home screen it gives me an error becose i didn't put the provider in my main file

this is my `cart_model.dart` file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CartItem {
  String id;
  String title;
  double price;
  int quantity;
  String brandName;
  String image;
  String sku;

  CartItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.price,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.image,
    required this.brandName,
    required this.sku,
  });

  void decrementQuantity() {
    if (quantity > 0) {
      quantity--;
    }
  }

  void incrementQuantity() {
    quantity++;
  }
}

class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  void clearCart() {
    items.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  double getTotalPrice() {
    double total = 0.0;
    for (CartItem item in items) {
      total += item.price * item.quantity;
    }
    return double.parse(total.toStringAsFixed(2));
  }

  int getProductQuantity(String id) {
    int index = items.indexWhere((item) => item.id == id);
    if (index >= 0) {
      return items[index].quantity;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  void updateItemQuantity(String sku, int newQuantity) {
    int index = items.indexWhere((item) => item.sku == sku);
    if (index >= 0) {
      items[index].quantity = newQuantity;
      if (items[index].quantity <= 0) {
        removeItem(sku);
      } else {
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
  }

  void removeOneItem(String id) {
    int index = items.indexWhere((item) => item.id == id);
    if (index != -1) {
      if (items[index].quantity > 1) {
        items[index].quantity--;
      } else {
        items.removeAt(index);
      }
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void incrementQuantity(String sku) {
    int index = items.indexWhere((item) => item.sku == sku);
    if (index != -1) {
      items[index].incrementQuantity();
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void decrementQuantity(String sku) {
    int index = items.indexWhere((item) => item.sku == sku);
    if (index != -1) {
      items[index].decrementQuantity();
      if (items[index].quantity <= 0) {
        removeItem(sku);
      } else {
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
  }

  List<CartItem> items = [];

  void addItem(String id, double price, String title, String image, String sku,
      String brandName, int quantity, int availableStock) {
    int index = items.indexWhere((item) => item.id == id);

    if (index >= 0) {
      int totalDesiredQuantity = items[index].quantity + quantity;

      if (totalDesiredQuantity <= availableStock) {
        items[index].quantity = totalDesiredQuantity;
      } else {
        print("Unable to add more items - stock limit reached.");
      }
    } else {
      if (quantity <= availableStock) {
        items.add(CartItem(
          id: id,
          sku: sku,
          title: title,
          brandName: brandName,
          price: price,
          image: image,
          quantity: quantity,
        ));
      } else {
        print("Unable to add item - stock limit reached.");
      }
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeItem(String sku) {
    items.removeWhere((item) => item.sku == sku);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

can someone can help me with this issue

if you need more info lmk

Answer (score 0):

The error you are dealing with seems to be related to a replica GlobalKey inside the widget tree. In the provided code, it looks as if you've got a navigatorKey for your MaterialApp:

```
MaterialApp(   navigatorKey: NavigationService().NavigationKey,   // ... )
```

The NavigationService is probably growing a new GlobalKey instance whenever it is referred to as, and this could cause a replica key trouble.

A not unusual exercise is to make NavigationService a singleton, so it uses the same instance of GlobalKey at some stage in the app's lifetime. Here's an instance of ways you may put in force a singleton sample for NavigationService:

```
class NavigationService {
  static final NavigationService _instance = NavigationService._internal();

  factory NavigationService() {
    return _instance;
  }

  NavigationService._internal();

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigationKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}
```

If you are still going through troubles, it might be useful to test other elements of your code in which GlobalKey times are created and make sure that they observe the same sample to save you duplicates.